# py2exe packing data files

Tags: python, file, installation, py2exe

I have an app to pack that contains an image as data file and I tried to run this setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib

file_dati=[]
file_dati.append(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())
file_dati.append(('img1','C:\Users\MZompetta.000\Desktop\20130114_assortimenti\img1.gif'))

setup(console=[{"script": "Int_assortimenti.py"}],
       options = {
        "py2exe": {
            "dll_excludes": ["libzmq.dll", "MSVCP90.dll"]
        }
    }, data_files=file_dati
)
```

but I obtain this error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

the error is referred to the line: `data_files=file_dati`

I tried other ways to compose the data_files but no way.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import logging
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib
import shutil

distDir = "dist"

# Remove the build and dist folders
shutil.rmtree("build", ignore_errors=True)
shutil.rmtree("dist", ignore_errors=True)

try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.abspath(distDir))
except:
    logging.exception('')

data_files = matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
shutil.copyfile('C:\Users\MZompetta.000\Desktop\20130114_assortimenti\img1.gif', os.path.join(distDir, "img1.gif"))

setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {
            "dll_excludes": ["libzmq.dll", "MSVCP90.dll"],
            "dist_dir": distDir,
        }
    }
    data_files = data_files,
    console=[{"script": "Int_assortimenti.py"}],
)
```

Comment: I receive this error:  

File "setup.py", line 25
    "dist_dir": distDir
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ManuelZompetta, sorry, it seems that I forgot one comma here. Try this code again plz.

Comment: I used this code:
import os
import logging
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib
import shutil

distDir = "dist"

# Remove the build and dist folders
shutil.rmtree("build", ignore_errors=True)
shutil.rmtree("dist", ignore_errors=True)

try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.abspath(distDir))
except:
    logging.exception('')

data_files = matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
shutil.copyfile('C:\Users\MZompetta.000\Desktop\AAA\img1.gif', os.path.join(distDir, "img1.gif"))

setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {

Comment: options = {"py2exe": {
            "dll_excludes": ["libzmq.dll", "MSVCP90.dll"],
            "dist_dir": distDir
        }
    },
    data_files = data_files,
    console=[{"script": "Int_assortimenti.py"}],
)

all works fine. Thanks. M